# Start script with different account on W7

Tags: windows-7

I would like to create a shortcut on dekstop which would open the script as different user (admin account in different domain).
Actually I have something like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:domain\adminacc "C:\path of script\elevate32.exe Reset-Password.vbs"
```

I have saved my credentials in windows manager and file elevate32 in the folder with the script. Unfortunately when I run this, the only thing what i am getting is windows error that file reset-password.vbs wasn't found.
Could you please advise what am I doing wrong ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're just running `elevate32.exe` and `Reset-Password.vbs` would need to be placed in the current working directory where runas starts. From my experience that would be `C:\Windows\System32`. You could counter this by using a simple batch file that e.g. did the following:

```
cd /D "C:\Path to Script\"
elevate32.exe Reset-Password.vbs
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, I tried to put elevate32.exe and my script into C:\Windows\System32 folder and run {C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:domain\acc "C:\Windows\System32\elevate32.exe Reset-Password.vbs" }. Unfortunately it still gives me error: Windows cannot find Reset-Password.vbs.. I also tried your advised way, but the same error appears.. Can't it be, that the admin account is in different domain  as I'm actually loged in ?

Comment: That doesn't matter as you specify a full path for to run `elevate32.exe`. I'm unaware of how it works so check what parameters it accepts. In addition what was the output generated by the batch? You could also include a `PAUSE` at the end of the batch to make it wait for some input.